# Over think or overthink?

Tags: word-choice, compounds, orthography

I saw both *over think* and *overthink* are used. Are they correct? Is overthink preferable or I can use no matter which one?

Comment: It's mostly personal opinion.  "Overthink" is in the dictionary, so you could use either.

Comment: *Over think* doesn't make any sense in most of the contexts I can think of. As two words, it means *think on top of* or *replace one thought with another*. Only *overthink* means to think more than you should about something.

Comment: Don't overthink the problem, but I'll note that I don't recall ever seeing it as "over think"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct was that *over-* is a prefix and would not normally be spelled separately. Here's what [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/over-) has to say on the matter:

> a prefixal use of over, preposition, adverb, or adjective, occurring in various senses in compounds (*overboard; overcoat; overhang; overlap; overlord; overrun; overthrow*), and especially employed, with the sense of “over the limit,” “to excess,” “too much,” “too,” to form verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and nouns (*overact; overcapitalize; overcrowd; overfull; overmuch; oversupply; overweight*), and many others, mostly self-explanatory: a hyphen, which is commonly absent from old or well-established formations, is sometimes used in new coinages or in any words whose component parts it may be desirable to set off distinctly.

And for *overthink*

> [overthink](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/overthink?s=t)
>   verb -thinks, -thinking or -thought
>   to spend more time thinking about something than is necessary or productive

And as @Jason Bassford points out, the meaning could change if you separate them (in this, or other cases). So I recommend writing them together: **overthink**.

Answer (score 1):

**Overthink** is the correct way to spell it, but nobody would be confused by what you meant if you split them into separate words. Most English language spellcheckers would correct you for not using "overthink" though.

Comment: Because *over think* is wrong.